# Throw Exception catch childException... why not?

Tags: java, exception

Say I have a method `doSomething()` which throws a checked exception, then in my `main` method I enclose `doSomething()` in a `try catch`.

Question:
Say I `throws Exception` in `doSomething()`. Why can't I `catch (ChildException e)` in my `main` method?

I know I can't and that I must catch Exception, but I don't understand why.

`ChildException extends Exception.`

If I `throws ChildException` and `catch Exception`then there's no problem understandably so. Why not the other way round?

Comment: If I throw you a Dog and you are expecting an Animal, that is ok. If I throw you an Elephant and you are expecting a Dog you'll probably get squished. (No Animals were physically thrown in this comment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **can** catch `ChildException` in your main method, but because the method you call is defined as `throws Exception`, you will also have to catch `Exception`, because the compiler does not know that `doSomething` is **only** throwing `ChildException`. If that is what you want, then you should define `doSomething` as `throws ChildException` instead.

For example with your current setup you could do:

```
try {
    doSomething();
} catch (ChildException e) {
    // handle child exception
} catch (Exception e) {
    // handle other exceptions
}
```

As commented by [MC Emperor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/507738/mc-emperor), order of catch blocks is important, if you'd reverse the order and catch `Exception` first, then that block will also handle `ChildException`, and the `ChildException`-specific block will not be used.

Alternatively, change `doSomething()`:

```
public void doSomething throws ChildException {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Ahh makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Note: The order of the catch blocks is important. When you swap the two catch blocks, the catch block with the `ChildException` is never executed, because such exceptions are already caught.

Answer (score 1):

If your code throws `ChildException child`, you can catch it with `Exception parent` , because `ChildException extends Exception`, so `child` is assignable to `parent` i.e. you can write something like

```
Exception parent = child;
```

But if your code says you are throwing an `Exception`, the compiler takes you at face value and assumes that the exception type thrown by your method can be of  any subclass of `Exception` or of the class `Exception` itself.

For example , your method may throw another `ChildException2`. So, in that case it is not assignable to `ChildException`  in the catch clause of main method. The `ChildException2` is neither handled nor declared.

So, the compiler doesn't allow you to continue with just catching the `ChildException` and asks you to either catch the type `Exception` or declare it.